# trace of $\operatorname{End}(E)$-valued $p$-form

Tags: differential-geometry

$\eta\,$ is $\,\operatorname{End}(E)$-valued $p$-form. $\;d_D\,$ is exterior covariant derivative. $\,E\,$ is Bundle.

How can I prove $$\,\operatorname{tr}(d_D\eta)=d(\operatorname{tr}(\eta))\quad ?$$

Comment: Write down the definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proofs like this entail "unpacking" the respective definitions, (recall your earlier post: [Exterior covariant derivative of $\operatorname{End}(E)$-valued $p$-form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424323/exterior-covariant-derivative-of-ende-valued-p-form?rq=1), e.g., and see also [Taking trace of vector-valued differential forms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3194/taking-trace-of-vector-valued-differential-forms?rq=1)) and then showing that *by definition,* $$\,\operatorname{tr}(d_D\eta)=d(\operatorname{tr}(\eta))$$

Comment: Nice links with answer +1